# minimum distance for 3 points to stand on a line

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

We have the coordinates of 3 points like $A$, $B$ and $C$ how to calculate the minimum distance $x$ such that if we move $A$, $B$, and $C$ at most $x$ meters they stand in a line

Comment: What is your work on this interesting problem ? Where are you blocked ? Have you taken particular cases ?

Answer (score 1):

**A bounding value for $x_{min}$ that should be also its exact value**

Let us denote by $A,B,C$ the points (not the same as the $A,B,C$ of the question that will be named here: $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$). We are going to prove that:

> $x_{min} \leq x_0$ where $x_0$ is the half of the length of the *shortest altitude* of triangle $ABC$, say $AH$.

Consider  (see picture below) the three circles with centers $A,B,C$ and common radius $x_0$ and line $B'C'$, where $B'$ (resp. $C'$) is the midpoint of $AC$ (resp. $AB$). The points of tangency $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are, as desired, aligned points at distance $x$ from $A,B,C$.

As said in the first sentence, I am almost sure that inequality $x_{min} \leq x_0$ is in fact an equality $x_{min}=x_0$ but I have no rigorous proof at the moment. A possible track: using Radon Transform ?

[image]

Comment: Using points $A$,$B$ and $C$ as in the question, let $d_A$ be the distance we move point $A$. Likewise $d_B$ and $d_C$. I tried to minimize $d_A+d_B+d_C$ and got the answer as the length of the shortest altitude of triangle $ABC$. If instead I minimize $max(d_A,d_B,d_C)$ then that gives me your answer. I also don't have a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I don't know if you have seen this question. I have obtained a sufficient condition ; could it be transformed into a necessary and sufficient condition ?